# FormCollection not posting a input value

Tags: c#, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get two input values from a view and pass them to controller using FormCollection.

These values change is based in a double click in a table row as you can see in jquery code below.

When i tried the first time only with id_artigo it worked! Then, when i tried do the same with descricao, it return the same view because descricao isn't geting the value.

id_artigo is an integer and descricao is a string.

What am i doing wrong ?

```
public ActionResult Create(NebluViewModel necessidadeModel, FormCollection collection)


necessidadeModel.NecessidadesModel.id_artigo = int.Parse(collection["label"]);
necessidadeModel.NecessidadesModel.descricao = collection["labelD"];
```

```
<div class="form-group">
      <span class="id-label"></span>
      <input type="hidden" id="label" name="label" value="" />
</div>


<div class="form-group">
      <span class="id-labelD"></span>
      <input type="hidden" id="labelD" name="labelD" value="" />
</div>
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable();

        $('#example tbody').on('dblclick', 'tr', function () {
            let $tr = $(this);

            if ($tr.hasClass('selected')) {
                $tr.removeClass('selected');
            } else {
                table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
                $tr.addClass('selected');
                $('#classModal').modal('hide');

                let targetValue = $tr.find('td:first').text();
                let targetDesc = $tr.find('td:nth-child(3)').text();

                $('.id-label').text(targetValue);
                $('#label').val(targetValue);

                $('.id-labelD').text(targetDesc);
                $('#labelD').val(targetDesc);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Update**

After check using DevTools, my input values are getting the right values. Only "label" is being passed to controller. I can't understand why "labelD" isn't.

Comment: Have you tried to debug on DevTools? Does `targetDesc ` have value?

Comment: Yeah, targetDesc get the valeu but apparently the value isn't reaching the controller. The targetValue is working